# Сессии, авторизация

Tags: c++, qt, сессия, qt5, auth

Пишу небольшое клиент-серверное приложение на `Qt5`, встал вопрос об авторизации.
Подскажите актуальные алгоритмы для безопасной авторизации и генерации `ID` сессии, был бы рад полистать готовые реализации и примеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Частично на этот вопрос отвечает " RFC 2617 - HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication ".Возможно, доступное по  этой [ссылке](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2617.html).
В целом, передавайте хешированный ключ с солью (т.е. по каналу связи следует передавать только хеш-сумму). На стороне сервера хешируйте ключ пользователя с той же солью и сравнивайте **хеши**. Такой вид аутентификации используется в линукс при авторизации, например. Смотрите также "дайджест-аутентификация".

Upd: @Timofey Bondarev, спасибо за ценное замечание.

Answer (score 2):

Категорически не рекомендую использовать всякие srand() + rand() для генерации чувствительных данных. На винде вполне можно использовать CryptGenRandom из CryptoAPI. В линухах, говорят, /dev/urandom.